# How to remove newlines (\n) from HTML page for CSV?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, newline

I'm parsing an HTML page with BS4:

```
from bs4 import BeuatifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('table')[1]
print("table is ", table)
rows = table.find_all('tr')
row_list = list()

for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    row_list.append(row)
    print("Row is ", row)
```

This works, but I'm getting some `\n`'s when I go to print the statements. This is messing up my CSV file. The new line is coming from the source code, which I obviously can't remove. Here's an example of a print line:

```
 Row is  ['\n        188', '\n        192', '\nPlayer1\n', '78', '271.3', '40,147', '148']
```

The `HTML` for that is:

```
<tr id="Row34261">
<td class="">
    188</td>

<td class=" hidden-print hidden-small hidden-medium ">
    192</td>

<td class="player-name">
<a href="/players/player.html">Player1</a>
    </td><td class="hidden-small hidden-medium">78</td>
<td>271.3</td>
<td class="hidden-small hidden-medium">40,147</td>
<td class="hidden-small hidden-medium">148</td>
</tr>
```

I have read through some other posts and see that `regex` or `strip()` might be of use, but that's where I get lost.

Comment: you can use `i.text.strip()` or `i.get_text(strip=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are iterating over the `td` you need to remove whitespace with `strip`:

```
...

for tr in rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text.strip() for i in td]
    row_list.append(row)
    print("Row is ", row)
```